# How to set GCP in local coordinates system to images to be processed with ODM

Tags: opendronemap

I have a drone survey of a local area of 200x200 meters. I have about 45 photos.

6 photogrammetric control points were placed on the ground and measured with centimeter precision from topographic instruments.

The local coordinates system is not georeferenced, nor are there any intentions to georeference it.  So I need to adjust and reference the photogrammetric model to the local coordinates system.

I am running a dockerized version of OpenDroneMap, to which I must pass a list of references between the coordinates of the control points in the local system and in the image system, for each image in which each point are viewed.

I ran a node and a web interface only to reference the images but it seems that I can only reference them in geographic coordinates.

How can I set GCPs with local coordinates, to images to be processed with OpenDroneMap?

Comment: Georeferencing the control is the simple solution.  In and case...Your control points are in meters to some arbitrary datum?  Maybe re-write the EXIF positions of the images such that they too map to your local system. Then run ODM as normal and tell ODM your GCPs are in some UTM.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, control points are in meters, but there isn't any datum associated with them (at least any geographic one). I understand that georeferencig GCPs is the simple solution, but it is just not possible right now. I removed all exif metadata and processed only with GCPs in a random UTM system. All image parameters were computed and the model was adjusted to the local system. Now I don't know if that is the best solution. Referencing the images was a challenge (using GDAL georeference plugin in QGIS). And I would prefer to not remove all metadata, but don't know how to edit it.

Comment: There is always a Python solution but this is a lot to tackle if it is just for one flight.  https://pypi.org/project/exif/